# How to programmatically concat data into SQL Server columns to match the max_value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, sql-insert

We are using `STUFF` to insert data into a table, adjusting some of the columns in the process with `CASE` statements that change the data to meet specific needs to data testing.

Is there a similar way to add additional data to a column on insertion without having to know ahead of time what space is left in the column?

So if I find a column First_Name that has a length of 15 and the row I am inserting has the name John how to make the insertion look like JohnAAAAAAAAAAA while also handling a case where the name might be Steve and I want A's to fill up the rest of the space.

I thought that getting the `max_length` from `sys.columns` and knowing the index of the existing value (maybe using PATINDEX) and I could somehow add in the required data to fill up the space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the `REPLICATE()` and `LEN()` functions, as below:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (NAME VARCHAR(15))

INSERT INTO @Table (Name) VALUES ('John')
INSERT INTO @Table (Name) VALUES ('Jeremiah')
INSERT INTO @Table (Name) VALUES ('Jehosaphat')

SELECT 
    Name,
    Name + REPLICATE('A', 15-LEN(Name))
FROM @Table
```

Another example would be by using the `LEFT()` function to determine the size of the returned string, which consists of your value and the concatenated text. Here's one way of doing that, this time on the `INSERT` side:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (NAME VARCHAR(15))

INSERT INTO @Table (Name) (SELECT LEFT('John' + REPLICATE('A', 15), 15))
INSERT INTO @Table (Name) (SELECT LEFT('Jeremiah' + REPLICATE('A', 15), 15))
INSERT INTO @Table (Name) (SELECT LEFT('Jehosaphat' + REPLICATE('A', 15), 15))

SELECT 
    Name 
FROM @Table
```

**EDIT 1:** 
The code below will update your data after the insert - since you logically will not know what the maximum length is until after you have loaded all the records, I'm inserting the names and then going back to update them after the fact.

```
-- Prepare data
DECLARE @Table TABLE (NAME VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('John'), ('Jeremiah'), ('Jehoshephat'), ('John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt')

-- Check it: a set of names with varying values
SELECT Name 
FROM @Table 

-- Determine and store the maximum character length
DECLARE @MaxLen INT
SET @MaxLen = (SELECT MAX(LEN(NAME)) FROM @Table)

-- update each record to pad with 'A' until the maximum character length is reached
UPDATE @Table
SET NAME = NAME + REPLICATE('A', @MaxLen - LEN(NAME))

-- Confirm it works as expected
SELECT * 
FROM @Table
```

Comment: Those look like they would work, and I can get them to work on those tables I want to note the length of, but is there a way to get the remaining length programmatically?  I have about 10 fields that all have different length variables and ideally I'd just determine the number of A's to add by the max_length and whatever is already input

Comment: I've pushed an edit - is it okay if this is a two-step operation, with the first step inserting and the second step updating?  Otherwise, I don't see how you plan on determining the max length before all records have been loaded.

Comment: I may end up doing it the way with your edit, since its hard to add a sub query to the STUFF select statement so I can work out the length I need to add.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using stuff you can explicitly append a padding and then use left function to get only desired length, something like this....

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Name VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @T VALUES ('John'),('Steve')

SELECT Name 
      ,NameNew = LEFT(Name + 'AAAAAAAAAA',10)
FROM @T



RESULT:

╔═══════╦════════════╗
║ Name  ║  NameNew   ║
╠═══════╬════════════╣
║ John  ║ JohnAAAAAA ║
║ Steve ║ SteveAAAAA ║
╚═══════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: If I wasn't adding this into a Stuff insert already probably, but I am constrained by it